# Js: detect page language and edit CSS attributes

Tags: javascript

in my code below i wanted to change some wp website strings texts depending on available language .. i was able to get the console result active language for ex tr but the if statement is not working .. any help?

```js
var language = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].getAttribute("lang");
console.log(language);

    if (language =='tr') {
        document.getElementsByClassName("size-botiga-large")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain there is always a `lang` attribute on the HTML element?

Comment: Not really but i need to code it in a way so that i can detect language and change attributes depending on it @Sampson

Comment: Is this for your own WordPress site, or is your code running in a Browser Extension or User Script? If it's your own site, you should do string-replacement server-side, based on the request header.

Comment: it's WordPress and i'm using WPML string translator but unfortunately it's not working with all strings and i need to code it in js

Comment: `window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language` will resolve to ISO 639-1 country code

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That's the user's language, but not necessarily the document language. Good suggestion though, since it is not quite clear from the question if these are expected to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly encourage you to seek out and solve this problem from the server-side, as JavaScript-based string-replacement on the user's device is considerably less ideal. That being said, here's a simple approach to your question:

```js
function languageBasedChanges () {
    // Start by getting the language from the documentElement (i.e. <html>)
    const language = document.documentElement.getAttribute("lang");

    // If no such attribute exists, `null` will be returned
    if ( !language ) {
        // No language found
        return;
    }
    
    // Assuming a string was returned, we'll test its lowercase form
    switch ( language.toLowerCase() ) {
        case "en":
            // Do something for English
            break;
        case "tr":
            // Do something else for Turkish
            break;
        default:
            // Unsupported, or missing, language code
    }
}
```

If you're looking to do string-replacement on the client with JavaScript, you should consider simplifying the process by adding [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to labels to make it easier to look-up the appropriate string for that element:

```html
<h1 data-label="pageHeader">Hello, World!</h1>
<h2 data-label="pageExplainer">This is my page.</h2>
```

Now that we have a consistent `data-label` attribute, we can use them to swap-out strings based on [the user's preferred language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language):

```js
// Some dictionary of languages and strings
const strings = {
    'en': {
        'pageHeader': 'Hello, World!',
        'pageExplainer': 'This is my page.'
    },
    'tr': {
        'pageHeader': 'Selam Dünya!',
        'pageExplainer': 'Bu benim sayfam.'
    }
}

// A function to find translatable elements
function replaceStrings () {

    // Get the user's language and all translatable elements
    const language = navigator.language.substring(0, 2);
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-label]");
    
    if ( language in strings === false ) {
        console.log('Unsupported language.');
        return;
    }

    // Cycle over all elements that need to be translated
    for ( const element of elements ) {
        const label = element.dataset.label;
        if ( label in strings[ language ] ) {
            element.textContent = strings[ language ][ label ];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you.. but i used ur code with   document.getElementsByClassName("orderby").style.color = "red"; 
 inside en language and nothing changed

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a list (i.e. an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) of elements, so you cannot call `.style` immediately after. You'd need to choose one of the elements in the list, or cycle over all of them with a loop, to call the individual `.style` properties of each.

Comment: var newText = document.getElementsByClassName('onsale')[0];
newText.innerHTML = 'new text here'; even not working

Comment: If you're going to use `document.getElementsByClassName`, you'll need to make sure this code is only ran once the elements have been loaded into the document. If the code runs before the page has been fully-loaded, then no elements will be found. Make sure that code goes within a *DOMContentLoaded* callback.